# Error while upgrading Angular material to v9 : ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity ɵngcc3.MatCardModule to symbol

Tags: angular-material, importerror, angular9, ng-modules

While upgrading to angular v9 following the angular update guide, updated angular core, cli and primeng to v9; but after migrating angular material to v9, it automatically deeply imports modules for all required components and other .ts files but not in the common.js file; it first gives errors related to imports in js file which says -

> error NG1010: Value at position 2 in the NgModule.imports of XModule is not a reference: [object Object]

After deeply importing the modules in js file, the error goes like -

> ERROR in Cannot resolve type entity ɵngcc3.MatCardModule to symbol

Note: Tried out a few solutions like - Deleted and re-installed node modules, deeply imported modules, changed configuration of enabling and disabling ivy, set target config to es2015, set script for postinstall as ngcc, set preserveSymLinks in compiler options.

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution? I am getting same error, I have update from V11 to V12

Comment: same error ....

Comment: Cloning the repo afresh and installing the node modules worked for me!